# Swing star rating

Tags: java, swing, rating

Is there any Swing Star rating widget.. am thinking of implementing my own .. but finding one will save me so much time

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this one:

[Star Rating Panel for Java Swing](http://blog.noblemaster.com/2010/08/31/star-rating-panel-for-java-swing/)

Sample code to use the **StarRater** (using the example from the comments):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        StarRater starRater = new StarRater(5, 2, 1);
        starRater.addStarListener(
            new StarRater.StarListener()   {

                public void handleSelection(int selection) {
                    System.out.println(selection);
                }
            });
        panel.add(starRater);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have came across this .. but it does not appear to work for me .. it lacks good installation manual .. have u tried it ? can u give me some details please

Comment: There is no installation necessary.  Just create the StarRater widget and use it as you would any other.  https://gist.github.com/768277

Comment: this is what i did .. and its not working
        StarRater starRater = new StarRater(5, 2, 1);
        starRater.addStarListener(new StarRater.StarListener() {

            public void handleSelection(int selection) {
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
        });
        this.add(starRater);

Comment: i found my error .. i was trying to add it to a JPanel .. so i had to change the layout for that panel .. thanks a lot